# Getting A Certain Part Of A Url

Tags: php, parse-url

How can i get a certain part of a URL i have searched google and read a few tutorials but can't seem to get my head around it maybe someone can show me from the example below.

Here is my code

```
<?php

include "simple_html_dom.php";

$title = "fast";

$html = file_get_html("http://www.imdb.com/find?q=".urlencode($title)."&s=all");
$element = $html->find('[class="result_text"] a', 1);
$link = $element->href;
echo $link;

// Clear dom object
$html->clear(); 
unset($html);

?>
```

Now this echos

```
/title/tt0109772/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2
```

But i only want the imdb id.

```
tt0109772
```

So can someone explain or show me how to do this please

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's always the subdir:

```
echo basename(dirname($link));
```

Comment: This is awesome! Much cleaner than `explode`

Answer (score 1):

you can Use `explode()`:

```
$str = "/title/tt0109772/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2"; 
$arrUrl = explode("/",$str);
$id = $arrUrl[2];
echo $id;
```

[demo](https://eval.in/108563)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode` like:

```
$parts = explode("/", $url);
```

This will split URL to array. Then check what index you want.. and get it like:

```
$id = $parts[3];
```

You can debug with: `print_r($parts);`

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant way, but

```
$link = '/title/tt0109772/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2';
$imdb_id = explode('/', $link);
$imdb_id = $imdb_id[2];
echo $imdb_id;
```

Will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4491655/3079918))

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = explode('/', $path);
```

Then I think you need `$segments[1]` to get the IMDB id.